# Pretty URL's with CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I'm fairly new to CI and have been trying out how to produce clean URL's. I have accomplished this task before without using a framework by editing my .htaccess file as follows.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(css|js|img)/
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

With CI, I have tried the following:

```
#Get rid of the index.php that's in the URL by default
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

# Profile page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(css|js|img)/
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ profile?id=$1 [L]
```

I know that by default, the value after the name of the controller in the URL (in this case, the Profile controller), will invoke the function with the same name inside the controller class. But, if there is no value in the URL specified after the controller, by default, the index function will be invoked. I plan on leaving the function name blank so that the index function will be invoked by default. But, the rewrite rule isn't working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just use CI's routes to handle the profile URL structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `.htaccess` you  can do like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

# Profile page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(css|js|img)/
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ profile/index/$1 [L]
```

In rewrite you have to mention the function name whether it is the index function or any other

Same as you can utilize the CI routing `routes.php`

```
$route['profile/(:any)']    = "profile/index/$1";
```

Now in index function of profile you can get the parameter

```
function index($id) {
echo $id;
echo $this->uri->segment(3);
//Both will result the same 
}
```

Comment: This works well. But, when I try to expand on this by adding a second variable using $route['users/(:num)/(:num)'] = "users/index/$1/$2"; in the routes.php file, it doesn't work when the second variable is missing in the URL. The $2 variable is optional. It doesn't have to be there. But, if it is in the URL, it should work.

Comment: So rewrite the both the routes in the routes.php first with single parameter and then for other