# Hiding controller and method from the URL but show only title name

Tags: php, codeigniter

I looked at the suggested answer(possible duplicate as stakoverflow says). It provided help but didn't solve the problem as it won't help create clean URL as per my needs. It has controller as part of the URL which I don't want to see as mentioned below.

I am developing a tutorial site in Codeigniter, and looking for a way to generate SEO friendly URL like

`www.crdlabs.com/how-to-use-multidimensional-arrays`

instead of

`www.crdlabs.com/home/index/how-to-use-multidimensional-arrays`.

Can anyone share his ideas? Thank you

Comment: Look into URL rewrites. Start by Googling "pretty URLs" or similar. It's a very common practice. No need to ask here.

Comment: Hi Stuart. Thanks for the message. I have achieved rewriting URLs in my earlier applications. Since I started working with codeigniter I am a bit unsure of the techniques to get pretty urls keeping MVC architecture in mind.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584883/pretty-urls-with-codeigniter

Comment: @Stuart. Thanks. I read that answer before asking here as I have used the same method in my previous applciation without MVC. As I am using codeigniter, it seems to be a bit different with the routing. Thanks for the efforts

Comment: That question is about CodeIgniter. The given answer should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pretty URL's with CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584883/pretty-urls-with-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to hide the **index.php** from URL so create the *.htaccess* file on the root folder and add this code

**.htaccess**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on                       
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then open the routes.php file in the **application/config/routes.php** location
and add this

```
$route['how-to-use-multidimensional-arrays'] = 'home/how-to-use-multidimensional-arrays';
```

This will work as URL as SEO friendly

Comment: Your new URL is like **www.crdlabs.com/how-to-use-multidimensional-arrays**

Comment: Thanks for the help. There is no index.php file but index() which is a method of controller Home(). I removed the index.php before asking the question here using .htaccess file. I hope you are closer to giving the perfect solution. Your routing has to work for as many pages as I create in my application. but this "$route['how-to-use-multidimensional-arrays'] = 'home/how-to-use-multidimensional-arrays'; " seems to work only for the title inside $route[]; I need a routing that should take care of routing for all. Any more advise from you is greatly appreciated.

Comment: as per this answer we are commenting to, you need to use the routes see https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Add this to ur root .htaccess file :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?title=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Then in ur index.php get the title $title = $_GET['title'] and do what ever you like with it like do a query in ur database and return data based on the title !

Comment: better of using the routes.php file to manage this instead of this method..

Comment: The controller is always same ? @user7321290

Comment: Yes, but I just don't want it to show up in the URL. I plan on creating a new controller for displaying the webpages.

Comment: @user7321290 well i'm not sure if it will work for u or not, but I will update my answer !